# How good are the resharper 5.0 nightly builds?

Tags: resharper, resharper-5.0

They have pretty low stars....

is it at least equivilent of 4.5?  or is it just a pain to use?

http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty stable and solid.
Stability depends on area you are developing (ASP.NET, XAML, WinForms).

Answer (score 1):

I have found it to be pretty good. I'm not using it on my production machine yet. I only have it running on my machine at home. I have not tried any of the ASP.NET or WPF stuff yet. The performance is acceptable but I'm hoping it gets better. Performance wise it is below 4.5 right now, but it is early. I will use it more when it is ready for vs2010 beta 2.

Haven't tried any of the new functionality. I'm just using the basics (rename, find usages, pull up member).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's pretty stable. I use it for production and the added features is worth the minor instabilities and errors.
If you need stability I'd stay with 4.5 (they've started nightly builds for version 4.5.2 which includes speedup for unit testing).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it yet, but as you can see when clicking the "Fixes" links, there are quite a lot of bugs that are being fixed for each new build. So probably you should expect that the software still has "some" bugs at such an early stage.

Although I can add, that I'm regularly using R# 4.5 nightly builds, and so far I never had any serious problems with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are good, yes there have been a few that are utterly broken, but you neither pay for or expect a nightly build of a beta product to work.

I too use it for production and have few complaints.

As for the start, I pay exactly no attention to them :)

Answer (score 0):

We are using v.5 and noticed there are some bugs (remember this is still pre-prod version)
Some of releases were completely unstable, but most of them are pretty stable

Besides of that: new features coming with version 5 are so valuable so we decided to use betas in prod and live with some  inconveniences :)

What we are doing:
before installing release one of us tests it on own box and if recognize it stable all switch to it.
We are not installing newest release daily. Just using day before version, looking on mark (stars) and comments (sometime appears 'broken'...)